# Find $\text{E}(X2^X)$ for $X\sim\text{Po}(3)$

Tags: probability, generating-functions

> Let $X\sim\text{Po}(3)$. Find $\text{E}(Y), \; Y:=X2^X$. HINT: First consider the random variable $Z:=Xs^{X-1}.$

My attempt:

$X$ is poisson distributed with $\lambda=3$. This means that $\text{P}(X=k)=e^{-3}\frac{3^k}{k!}$.

Hence the generating function of $X$ is $$\phi_X(s):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \text{P}(X=k)s^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-3}\frac{3^k}{k!} s^k$$

(note that $\phi_X(s) = \text{E}(s^X)$)

Hence
$\phi_X'(s)=\text{E}(Xs^{X-1})=\text{E}(Z)$

Let $T:=X-1$ then $X=T+1$ and
$$\text{E}(Z)=\text{E}((T+1)s^T)=\text{E}(Ts^T)+\text{E}(s^T)$$
$$= \text{E}(Ts^T)+\phi_T(s)$$

But I do not know how to go on from here. I think I have a more complicated expression that the one I started with, how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have to use the hint?Looks like it can be computed directly quite quickly.

Comment: Since the answer is below you could also compute $$E [Y]=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty }{r{{.2}^{r}}.\frac{{{3}^{r}}{{e}^{-3}}}{r!}}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty }{.\frac{{{6}^{r}}{{e}^{-3}}}{(r-1)!}}={{e}^{3}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{.\frac{{{6}^{k+1}}{{e}^{-6}}}{k!}}=6{{e}^{3}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{.\frac{{{6}^{k}}{{e}^{-6}}}{k!}}=6{{e}^{3}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it now, thanks to @madprob

$$\phi'(2)=E(X2^{X-1})=E(X2^X2^{-1})=1/2E(Y)$$
thus
$$E(Y)=2\phi'(s)$$

$$2\phi'(s)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-3}\frac{3^k}{k!}k2^{k-1} = ... =6e^{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done.
What is the relation between $\phi'_{X}(2)$ and $Y$?

Also,
\begin{align*}
 \phi_{X}(s) &= \ldots 
 = \exp(3s-3)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-3s)(3s)^k}{k!}
 = \exp(3s-3)
\end{align*}

Comment: $\phi_X'(2) = E(X2^{X-1})-E(2^{X-1})$ I not see how I can formulate this in terms of $2^X$

Comment: Didn't you write $\phi'_X(s) = E[Xs^{X-1}]$?

Comment: Ahh yes, I had that at first, I am getting a bit confused now, sorry, my first comment is wrong

Comment: I think I got it now $\phi'(2)=1/2E(X2^X)$

Comment: Indeed! Now you can obtain $E[Y]$ by computing $\phi'(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $X\sim \text{Poi}(\lambda)$, then
$$
EX2^{X}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k2^k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}
=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\frac{(2\lambda)^k}{k!}
=e^{-\lambda}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}\right)\bigg|_{x=2\lambda}
=e^{-\lambda}2\lambda e^{2\lambda}.
$$
Thus
$$
EX2^X=2\lambda e^\lambda.
$$
If $X\sim\text{Poi}(3)$, then
$$
EX2^X=2(3)e^{3}=6e^3.
$$